# What does "lend an added dimension" mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, idioms

I encountered this expression in an article about sailing.

The complete sentence is as below:

> > The floor of the vessel is so comfortable to walk in barefoot, lending an added dimension to the sailing mantra 'Spirit of Freedom'

I couldn't find the definition on internet. Please help me understand this.

Comment: ***Lend*** = ***give / provide / impart***. And a metaphorical ***added dimension*** means another way of seeing / evaluating the referent (usually, revealing some *positive* aspect).

Answer (score 2):

**dimension**  [longman's](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dimension)

a part of a situation or a quality involved in it.  *the moral

 dimension of world politics.*

**add a new/an extra/another etc dimension** (to something):  *His coaching has added another dimension to my game*

political/social/economic etc dimension:  *It is important to keep in mind the historical dimension to these issues.*

Coming back to your question: "Spirit of Freedom" likely refers to the feeling of physical freedom when sailing, and walking barefoot makes the author feel 'free' in another sense - perhaps free from social constraints. But regardless of the types of freedom actually intended, "lend an extra dimension" refers to experiencing some extra quality of freedom by going barefoot comfortably.

Answer (score 1):

This can in a more common phrasing be compared with the phrasing

"Taking something to a whole new level"

https://brightside.me/wonder-people/17-people-who-took-kindness-to-a-whole-new-level-430760/

The presented link will give you an example as to how a act of kindness in a common sense bettering another person is "overdone" to such an extent it seems they empowered the act of kindness and lifted it to a level yet unseen.

"lending an added dimension to the sailing mantra 'Spirit of Freedom'"

Can probably be interpreted as:

Allowing the mantra "Spirit of Freedom", to elevate its purpose, meaning and goal.

A whole new level, level being defined as a new dimension as the comfort level inhabits "such great comfort" it deserves a new dimension to exist in and we will for a limited time lend this temporary dimension to the previously stated mantra for a short period of time - and simply live there for that time being.